# Excel VBA Macros Format rows based on Values

Tags: vba, excel

Hey guys I have a table that I want to format with vba as it is a lot of values and it takes way too long formatting one by one.

example

Client ID ---------- Employee ---------- Hours

0001 ------------------Josh  -------------5

0001 ------------------Carl  -------------5

0001 ------------------Joe  --------------5

0005 ------------------Ken  --------------5

0005 ------------------Jeff --------------5

0008 ------------------Joe  --------------5

0008 ------------------Josh  -------------5

0009 ------------------Carl  -------------5

0011 ------------------Joe  --------------5

0011 ------------------Carl --------------5

I want to apply a border underneath the last of the same ClientID to separate them from the rest of the ClientID's so that it is easier to read when looking at information so the output should be something like this:

Client ID ---------- Employee ---------- Hours

0001 ------------------Josh  -------------5

0001 ------------------Carl  -------------5

0001 ------------------Joe  --------------5

---

0005 ------------------Ken  --------------5

0005 ------------------Jeff --------------5

---

0008 ------------------Joe  --------------5

0008 ------------------Josh  -------------5

---

0009 ------------------Carl  -------------5

---

0011 ------------------Joe  --------------5

0011 ------------------Carl --------------5

---

I am guessing I need some sort of loop that goes down ClientID Column and checks each ClientID..as soon as a new ClientID shows up then Add a border to the top of that Row or Bottom of previous one. I know I should have some code, if anyone can point me in the right direction or give me some  clues I can continue to write something up.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you need to use VBA or can you use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: I need to use VBA/Macros as there are way too many rows to do it one by one or writing a formula for several columns. Basically I want to create a module that someone runs and it applies that formatting.

Comment: Does the data come out sorted by Client ID already or do you need to sort it first?

Comment: Data is already sorted from lowest to highest.

Comment: The headers are on Row1 and it starts at A below row 1 is the data. Same as you posted in your screenshot but there are more columns with more information. It is weird because when I copy the table into a separate sheet and run the code it works but it won't work inside the original sheet. I ADDED A SCREENSHOT OF MY SHEET IN THE ORIGINAL QUESTION ABOVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data that will be in the format of the picture below:

[image]

Then following macro will add a border when the Client ID changes.  This macro assumes that the Client IDs are already sorted, either ascending or descending.

**Macro**

```
Sub border()
'Macro valid & comments valid for Excel 2007 or greater

'Dimensions all the initial variables; it is good practice to declare all your variables at top and to capitalize one letter so that when VBA interprets the variable when you exit the row, it will automatically make the variable uppercase and you know you spelled it correctly

'variable for current row number when looping through all the data
Dim Ro As Integer
'variable for the maximum number of rows in the dataset
Dim mRo As Integer
'variable for the maximum number of columns in the dataset
Dim mCo As Integer

    'selects the first sheet in the active workbook to use as the parent object for all code contained in the WITH statement.  VBA is object oriented meaning there are a lot of parent-child relationships.  In this case, all the code inside the WITH statement is the parent, or containing object, and the internal code are the children objects
    With Sheets(1)
        'Determines last row in the range of all data
        'Uses .Rows.Count to find the last row in Excel (1,048,576 for Excel 2007+) and then goes all the way up (xlUp) until it hits a "different" type of cell.  Almost 99.9999% of the time, row 1,048,576 will be blank, so this will traverse up until it reaches the first non-blank row, or the bottom of our dataset.  This is similar to starting out at A1048576 and pressing Ctrl+Up Arrow
        mRo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'Same action as the row, but goes to the left until it reaches non-blank data
        mCo = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Removes borders from original table
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(mRo, mCo)).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone            

        'loops through data to compare when a Client ID changes
        'Starts are row 2 and performs a for loop until it reaches the end of the dataset at the mRo row
        For Ro = 2 To mRo
            'Checks to see if the client ID changes & applies a border
            'Looks to see if the row below (Ro + 1) in the first column (Client ID) is different from the current row's (Ro) first column.  If there is a difference, then the Client ID just changed and we want to add a border
            If .Cells(Ro, 1).Value <> .Cells(Ro + 1, 1).Value Then
                'Adds border to bottom of rows
                'The range is selected from the current row (Ro) first column to the current row (Ro) last column (mCo).  The formatting of the border was actually determined from using the VBA "Record Macro" function (if you don't see "Developer" in your ribbon bar, click on either FILE or the Office symbol in the upper left hand corner of Excel, go to OPTIONS, CUSTOMIZE RIBBON and check the DEVELOPER checkbox on the right hand side.  Then, you will see the DEVELOPER tab in the ribbon bar and you can use the "Record Macro" feature
                With .Range(.Cells(ro, 1), .Cells(ro, mCo)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I will test it out :) Do you happen to have some website for documentation and implementation I like to read them so I understand how it works and I learn it :)

Comment: A little from here, a little from there.  I will add a little more comments so you might be able to understand it a little better.

Comment: I tested it and everythign seems right but I get Run-Time error '1004': Method Range of Object _ worksheet failed

Comment: Do you think it is because of the With Sheets(1) part of the code it may be pointing to wrong sheet...the sheet I have is named FinalReport  however when I debug it points to Range(.Cells(ro, 1), .Cells(ro, mCo)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous being the part of the code not working...

idk if I should change With Sheets("FinalReport") which I did but then I get no error but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Which order is the "FinalReport" in the actual excel sheet?

Comment: And which cell does your data actually start at?  If it doesn't start at A1, then you will have to slightly modify it

Comment: The headers are on Row1 and it starts at A below row 1 is the data.  Same as you posted in your screenshot but there are more columns with more information.  It is weird because when I copy the table into a separate sheet and run the code it works but it won't work inside the original sheet. I ADDED A SCREENSHOT OF MY SHEET IN THE ORIGINAL QUESTION ABOVE.

Comment: Try adding a .Range rather than a Range

Comment: Okay I figured out what it is...Since I already have a code that is creating this worksheet from another2 worksheets and then copies it..it is creating this table with background and borders already which is why the code did not apply borders to it because as you see in the screenshot I added in the Question above it is not allowing it to overwrite that...So I manually selected the whole table and removed the borders and backgrounds etc and then ran the code and now it works...so my new question is how to remove the formatting and current borders first in a code so that I can then run the code

Comment: I have updated the code to remove borders and make the new border xlThick to stand out more against the table.

Comment: I was working on something similar like this

Sub NoBorders()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
Next ws
End Sub

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

With a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=$A1<>$A2
```

applied to A:C, or possibly by adding a blank row as a separator (for example with Subtotal at each change in Client ID - which could then be changed to a border).